# How to I calculate stock Returns in R from the dataframe I created?

Tags: r

Greetings there nice people,

I am doing a small project and I need to calculate the stock returns I have downloaded from the Thompson Datastream database, I have downloaded them in a time series format in excel when I import the data to R and press `class(data)` the dates are in a POSIXct format as you can see in the pic:

[image]

I run this code to convert POSIXct into Date after converting the excel file I import into dataframe:

```
mdaxin[] <- lapply(mdaxin, function(x) if(inherits(x, "POSIXct")) as.Date(x) else x)
```

it seems this converts the POSIXct into Date.

This is how my prices look in my `data.frame`:

[image]

Now I need to turn those prices into returns, there are 56 columns, how do I go about it so I do not have to calculate returns for each column?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: First, include some code and data for us to see (a MWE). Second, I'd try to have only one column with dates, instead one date column for each stock. If you merge them and create an `xts` object, you could run `TTR::ROC()` on it and you'd get returns.

Comment: thanks for the comment.
so my data were downloaded in excel in a time series format from the Thompson Datastream platform.

they look like the following:

there are 56 columns including dates and prices:

Date                   Stock1         Date           Stock2          Date             Stock3  
2020-10-02          40        2019-10-02           43         2018-10-02         21
2020-20-03          41        2019-10-02           32         2019-10-02         23   




.
.
.
.
.